# Git saving deploy token url from composer.json preventing pushing to repo

Tags: git, composer-php

I'm developing a module-based Laravel CMS.

This is private, which means I need to use git deploy tokens, so I can use composer for installing / managing these modules.

Example:

```
"repositories"      : {
"repo-name": {
  "type": "vcs",
  "url": "https://gitlab+deploy-token-xxxxx:password@gitlab.com/url-to-repo.git"
},
```

This generally works quite well, meaning when I create a new project, I can install my modules.

But Windows / Git saves the deployment token as Git credentials in Windows, overwriting my normal login.

This means that, when I'm developing my module and want to push changes, Gitlab denies it because Git is trying to upload my changes using the deploy key instead of my normal Git credentials.

My question: is it possible to somehow prevent Git from saving this deploy token as Git credential globally, so it does not overwrite my usual Git credentials?

Comment: Perhaps [api-credentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/api-credentials) does help?

Comment: I don't see any way to prevent deploy tokens from being saved with this api-credentials?

Answer (score 0):

> when I'm developing my module and want to push changes, Gitlab denies it because Git is trying to upload my changes using the deploy key instead of my normal Git credentials.

Check if [GitLab 14.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/12/22/gitlab-14-6-released/#use-deploy-tokens-to-download-composer-dependencies) (December 2021) applies in your case:

> ### Use Deploy Tokens to download Composer dependencies
>
> You can now use [deploy tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/index.html) to authenticate users who interact with the Composer repository. Previously, [personal access tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) and job tokens were used to authenticate users that published and downloaded composer dependencies from the GitLab Composer repository.
> These tokens are tied to a specific user.
>
> [Deploy tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/index.html) provide an authentication method that isn’t tied to specific users, ensuring that your production workflows are even more efficient and secure.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/composer_repository/#install-a-composer-package) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/240897).

Answer (score -1):

try remove `.git` in your url.

"url": "https://gitlab+deploy-token-xxxxx:password@gitlab.com/url-to-repo"

Comment: You response does not explain how it can solve the problem.